# Error While storing the document Permission denied AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I have a EC2 instance in elasticbeanstalk environment(dev) which works as expected. I have also deployed the same APP on a new elasticbeanstalk environment(Test). Application comes up and all the functionality works, but the upload to S3 functionality does't work in this TEST ENV. I get "Error While storing the document Permission denied" Exception. 
I have give all the permission in S3 for the bucket policy. My bucket policy details are as follow -

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy150025",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "Stmt1500252113871",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": "s3:*",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::dev/devkey"
}
]
}
```

I am not sure why the same APP works in One ENV and not the Other. Appreciate any suggestions.

*** Updated ***
Trust Relationship

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you check the trust relationship in iam role, whether it has a filter for previous environments ec2s

Comment: I don't see any specific filter applied to any ec2 instance. Here is the policy details -                                                                                                             
    {
      "Version": "2008-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
    }

Comment: Did you check in Trust relationships in Role? Whether only a specific EC2 can assume the role?

Comment: I have updated the question with IAM Role Trust relationship policy settings. I don't see any reference to a specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

bucket policy grants the user access to the objects, but the user who is uploading the files to the bucket should have put objects access to the bucket,
for the ec2 instance can you confirm the aws credentials inside machine env, or any role attached to the instance which is allowing to put objects into bucket.